# UISearchBar and UISegmentedControl Base Internalization Issue

Tags: uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISearchBar in a storyboard which displays the default text : "Search" in its search window. The storyboard has been base internationalized and I can see the translations for other languages in the .strings file for the storyboard. 
But when I switch languages the text "Search" wont change as per the language translation.

Is there a way to fix this ?

Similar thing happens with a Segmented Control.

The only way I have gotten it to work is set the text in code using NSLocalizedStringWithDetaultValue.
How to fix this in the storyboard?